# Importing relationships from CSV files

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import data from CSV files and while I've managed to import nodes, I can't figure out how to import relationships.

I've three files: Customer.csv, Orders_Test.csv, and Order_history.csv. The data is captured in different columns and rows. Customer.csv has two headers, Customer_ID and Name, and has the following data: 1 Jaap, 2 Victoria. The Orders_Test.csv has one header, Order_ID, with the following data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Order_history.csv has two headers, Customer_ID and Order_ID with the data (again in columns) 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 1 5, 2 6, 2 7, 2 8, 2 9, 2 10. In other words, in this file I have to customer that are linked to five orders each.

This is the code which I use to load/import the data:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Customer.csv' AS row 
CREATE (c:Customer {CustomerID: toInteger (row.Customer_ID), name: 
row.Name})

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Orders_test.csv' AS row 
CREATE (o:Order {OrderID: toInteger (row.Order_ID)})

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Order_history.csv' AS row
MATCH (c:Customer {CustomerID: row.Customer_ID})
MATCH (o:Order {OrderID: row.Order_ID}) 
MERGE (c)-[:ORDERED]->(o)
```

Importing the data regarding the customers and orders is not a problem, yet nothing happens when I execute the last load statement. When I have only one customer, the relationships are created, but not when I have two or more. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add the `toInteger` function, so you have to type mismatch :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Order_history.csv' AS row
MATCH (c:Customer {CustomerID: tointeger(row.Customer_ID)})
MATCH (o:Order {OrderID: toInteger(row.Order_ID)}) 
MERGE (c)-[:ORDERED]->(o)
```

Comment: Dear lord, how could I've missed this. Thanks for much for pointing that out!